# Forms ListView row index

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Just started to play with Xamarin.Forms and I have a question about ListView and no answer found on the web. In the code below, I need in the ItemTemplate to get the index of the element or a way to access the ItemSource displayed in the cell, as i need to build the path of the image displayed. Better if i can have both, the index and the element. Any way without using a CustomRenderer?

```cs
ListView listView = new ListView
{
    HasUnevenRows = true,

    // Source of data items.
    ItemsSource = DataManager.GetPeople(),

    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {

        // Create views with bindings for displaying each property.
        Label nameLabel = new Label();
        nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
        nameLabel.TextColor = Color.White;

        var relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout {};    

        var webImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill };
        image.HeightRequest = 200;
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(Path.Combine(path, "/people/263/1.jpg"));
        relativeLayout.Children.Add(image,Constraint.Constant(0),Constraint.Constant(0));

        relativeLayout.Children.Add(nameLabel,
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
                return parent.Width / 2 - nameLabel.Width / 2;
            }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Height - 20;
            }));

        // Return an assembled ViewCell.
        var viewCell = new ViewCell
        {
            View = relativeLayout
        };
        viewCell.Height = 200;
        relativeLayout.HeightRequest = 200;
        return viewCell;
    })
};
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using a converter. You can see from the example below how to access the element BindingContext(value) and index by passing the ListView as a reference. You could use a converter to build your image path and bind it to an image source.

```
public class ImageSourceIndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || parameter == null) return Color.White;
        var index = ((ListView) parameter).ItemsSource.Cast<object>().ToList().IndexOf(value);
        return ImageSource.FromFile(Path.Combine(path, "/people/"+index+"/1.jpg"));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then name your ListView and pass it as the parameter using x:Reference

```
<ListView x:Name="PeopleListView" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <Grid>
        <Image Source={Binding .,Converter={StaticResource StripedBackgroundIndexConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference PeopleListView}}" />
      </Grid>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: how does Binding . work and what is the "value" expected in the converter? your approach looks good to me but value is null for me always. it should be the current listview item not?

Comment: Very nice.  I used your technique to make alternating row backcolor between transparent and a semi-transparent.

Answer (score 4):

The "element" is the `ViewCell` `BindingContext`.

The "index" is the position of the element in the `ItemsSource`. If your `ItemsSource` is set to an `List<T>`, you can just use `IndexOf()`. If it's a true `IEnumerable()` you'll need to be a bit more smart. A dumb way (ok for short lists) would be:

```
ItemsSource.ToList().IndexOf (BindingContext);
```

Comment: But if I'm not wrong you can't access ItemsSource inside the DataTemplate.

Comment: Also in the DataTemplate in the example BindingContext is always null... quite strange..

Comment: is this even possible on xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Nice technique.  Short reply wouldn't let me share code.
I used your technique to make alternating rows of transparant and semi-transparent.

```
public class AlternatingHighlightColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
    Color rowcolor = Color.Transparent;
        if (value == null || parameter == null) return Color.White;
        var index = ((ListView)parameter).ItemsSource.Cast<object>().ToList().IndexOf(value);
        if (index % 2 == 0)
        {
            rowcolor = Color.FromHex("#55FFFFFF");
        }
        return rowcolor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```